# visual studio Regex Find all matching script tags?

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I want to find all instances of `<script>....</script>` tags in all my views in visual studio.

I have tried the following regex with no success.

```
((<script>.+?</script>)|('.+?'))
```

any ideas?

Comment: *"Any ideas?"* - Yes. [Use a parser](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (or write two paragraphs that explain why that isn't an option).

Comment: A wild guess: try `(?s)<script>.+?</script>` although this is not 100% safe...